# Registering an Object on DBus using pythons Gio-Bindings

Tags: python, dbus, gio

I'm working on a Python-Clone of an existing C-Project. The C-Project Connects to a custom DBus and offers a Object there for getting Callbacks.

I tried to replicate this using Python with code that basically boils down to:

```
def vtable_method_call_cb(connection, sender, object_path, interface_name, method_name, parameters, invocation, user_data):
    print('vtable_method_call_cb: %s' % method_name)

connection = Gio.DBusConnection.new_for_address_sync(
    "unix:abstract=gstswitch",
    Gio.DBusConnectionFlags.AUTHENTICATION_CLIENT,
    None,
    None)

node_info = Gio.DBusNodeInfo.new_for_xml(introspection_xml)

vtable = Gio.DBusInterfaceVTable()
vtable.method_call(vtable_method_call_cb)
vtable.get_property(None)
vtable.set_property(None)

connection.register_object(
    "/info/duzy/gst/switch/SwitchUI",
    node_info.interfaces[0],
    vtable,
    None,
    None)
```

The code fails when creating the vtable at the `vtable.method_call` call (but `get_property` fails, too, when I comment one call out) the following log/traceback:

```
** (process:18062): WARNING **: Field method_call: Interface type 2 should have is_pointer set
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "moo.py", line 69, in <module>
    vtable.method_call(vtable_method_call_cb)
RuntimeError: unable to get the value
```

I was not able to find code using `register_object()` in python, so I'm unsure if this part of Gio should be usable or if it's just not complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This certainly not what you'll want to hear, but you have hit a [4 year old bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=656325) in the GDBus Python bindings that makes it impossible to register objects on the bus. A patch had been proposed quite some time ago, but every time it looked like it was actually going to land, some GNOME developer found something he/she did not like something about it, a new patch was proposed... and nothing happend for most of the next year. This cycle has already happend 3 times and I do not know if there is much hope that it will be broken anytime soon...

Basically the GNOME developers themselves more or less [suggested that people use dbus-python until this issue is finally fixed](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=656325#c30), so I guess you should be heading [here instead](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/). :-/

BTW: I think you source code is wrong (aside from the fact that it won't work either way). To create the VTable you would actually be written something like this, I think:

```
vtable = Gio.DBusInterfaceVTable()
vtable.method_call  = vtable_method_call_cb
vtable.get_property = None
vtable.set_property = None
```

But since the bindings are broken you are just trading an exception with an `abort()` here... :-(

If the patch actually makes it into `python-gi` in the current form the `vtable` would be dumped entirely (YEAH!) and `connection.register_object` call would become:

```
connection.register_object_with_closures(
    "/info/duzy/gst/switch/SwitchUI",
    node_info.interfaces[0],
    vtable_method_call_cb, # vtable.method_call
    None,                  # vtable.get_property
    None)                  # vtable.set_property
```

## Update

It appears this has now finally been fixed! You can now export object using `g_dbus_connection_register_object_with_closures`:

```
def vtable_method_call_cb(connection, sender, object_path, interface_name, method_name, parameters, invocation, user_data):
    print('vtable_method_call_cb: %s' % method_name)

connection = Gio.DBusConnection.new_for_address_sync(
    "unix:abstract=gstswitch",
    Gio.DBusConnectionFlags.AUTHENTICATION_CLIENT,
    None,
    None)

node_info = Gio.DBusNodeInfo.new_for_xml(introspection_xml)

connection.register_object(
    "/info/duzy/gst/switch/SwitchUI",
    node_info.interfaces[0],
    vtable_method_call_cb,
    None,
    None)
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I accepted this as answer because it helps clarify the current situation regarding DBus in Python. I did not find that gnome-bug, so I'm very thankful for that Reference.

In the Meantime we rewrote our code, so that the C-Server is the only part registering objects and the Python-Clients get it's callbacks via signals -- signals are a way to push events on a Bus that is supported in Gio. This may or may not not suit the needs of others.